# Any reason why my Macbook is warming up extremely quickly?

Tags: macbook, cooling

I've had my Macbook pro 13" for about 10 days now and I haven't noticed anything until this morning. The macbook has been starting to heat up quicker than I thought it would. I started it and about 10 mins later my CPU has gone up 157F degrees and my heatsink has gone up to 140F.

Anyone know what might be causing this? I don't have any power-hungry apps running, just Chrome and iTunes.

BTW: I'm in San Francisco, so usually it's very chilly here and so I know it's not the outside environment.

Comment: Those temperatures look reasonable to me. What does Activity Monitor show for your CPU usage at this temperature?

Comment: Are you viewing any Flash-based sites?  I find with my 13" Macbook Aluminum unibody that it heats up pretty fast when running Flash.

Comment: CPU's 80-90% idle most of the time.